# Why is a button enabled if the Command binding resolves to null?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

OK, the XAML is quite simple and uses MVVM to bind to an `ICommand SomeCommand { get; }` property on a view model:

```
<Button Command="{Binding Path=SomeCommand}">Something</Button>
```

If `SomeCommand` returns `null`, the button is enabled. (Nothing to do with `CanExecute(object param)` method on `ICommand`, because there is no instance to call that method on)

And now the question: Why is the button enabled? How would you work it around?

If you press the "enabled" button, obviously nothing is called. It is just ugly that the button looks enabled.

Comment: "obviously nothing is called" -- That is not at all obvious. You might be handling the `Click` event somewhere, where the button does not know and has no way of knowing it will get handled.

Comment: I have no Click event subscriptions on the Button as you see.

Comment: The `Click` event, like most events, is routed. The containing element could be handling the event. The button has no way of knowing.

Comment: Nice insights. I am happy that I asked this question already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is enabled because that's the default state. Disabling it automatically would be an arbitrary measure that gives rise to other problems.

If you want to have a button without an associated command be disabled, bind the [`IsEnabled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.isenabled.aspx) property to `SomeCommand` using an appropriate converter, e.g.:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(object), typeof(bool))]
public class NullToBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value !== null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: That is exactly what I did. I just wonder what that "arbitrary measure" is.

Comment: @wigy: It's a way of saying "why should that be the default behavior?" As hvd points out, wouldn't it be fair game to not have a command at all and just handle the click event?

Comment: The philosophical question is whether there is a difference between a binding that has null as a source and no binding at all. How I understand is that if these 2 cases are treated the same way, the only choice is to enable the button when the binding source is null.

Comment: @wigy: Binding does not (and *should definitely* not!) come into it. If `Command` is null, which it is by default, you can't really have the button disabled as discussed. It doesn't matter where the null value comes from (i.e. if it's set from a binding or assigned locally or whatever).

Comment: Setting IsEnabled will override CanExecute of the command. It will override it even when the command is not null. I think the better solution is to use the fallback value.

Answer (score 8):

My colleague found an elegant solution: using a binding fallback value!

```
public class NullCommand : ICommand
{
    private static readonly Lazy<NullCommand> _instance = new Lazy<NullCommand>(() => new NullCommand());

    private NullCommand()
    {
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public static ICommand Instance
    {
        get { return _instance.Value; }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("NullCommand cannot be executed");
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And then the XAML looks like:

```
<Button Command="{Binding Path=SomeCommand, FallbackValue={x:Static local:NullCommand.Instance}}">Something</Button>
```

The advantage of this solution is that it works better if you break [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) and you have some dots in the binding path, where each instance might become `null`.

Answer (score 5):

Very similar to Jon's answer, you could use a style with a trigger to mark buttons which should be disabled when there is no command set.

```
<Style x:Key="CommandButtonStyle"
        TargetType="Button">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Command"
                    Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled"
                    Value="False" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

I prefer this solution because it addresses the problem very directly and it does not require any new types.

Comment: This is the best solution to the problem IMO