# Fallback values of complex object

Tags: c#, xaml, fallbackvalue

I can't figure out how to defined the fallback values of:

- A list, e.g. for a ComboBox ItemsSource
- A command, e.g. for a Button Command
- Other complex objects

I tried {x:Null} but doesn't seem to work:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Regions, FallbackValue={x:Null}}"
```

Comment: When you say "doesn't seem to work", what exactly do you mean? Did you record somehow what the output is, when the binding does not resolve and FallbackValue is called?

Comment: I did, this is what I have as warning raised: System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=DeleteCommand; DataItem=null; target element is 'TextBoxCombo' (Name='CurrentUserControl'); target property is 'DeleteCommand' (type 'ICommand')

Comment: Well, your example is for ICommands, I am not sure if FallbackValue of null would work on buttons, since they are always enabled by default. However, according to this answer here: [Why is a button enabled if the Command binding resolves to null?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18465023/6741868), you can set null using a binding fallback value. For 'Other complex objects' such as your ComboBox ItemsSource, the same method would work.